# Equating two Objects in JavaScript. On Changing one, second automatically changes

Tags: javascript

I am trying to use a hash map in a for loop:
But while resetting the second object, it is automatically changes Map values of the previous Key in the Hash Map.Please help me prevent this.
Code:

```
    for (i = 0; i < tds.length; ++i) {
        tdtext = $(tds[i]).text();
        //iIndex = tdtext.indexOf('Success')>-1 ? tdtext.indexOf('Success') : tdtext.indexOf('Failed');
        iIndex = 8;
        key = tdtext.substring(0, iIndex);
        outcome = tdtext.substring(iIndex);
        //var sCombine = sNum1 + sNum2;
        console.log(iIndex, outcome);

        //Reset oCount for next use
        var oCount = Object.create(null);
        oCount.total = 0; oCount.success = 0;//2. Here it is changing the vlaues assigned in step 1

        //Case 1: If map already has key
        if (map.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            //var ob = map.get(key);
            if (outcome === "Success")
            map[key].success++;
            map[key].total++;
        }

        //Case 2: If map doesn't have key
        else {
            if (outcome === "Success")
                oCount.success++;
            //If outcome is failure or success irrespective of that we increase the total count
            oCount.total++;
            map[key] = oCount;//1. Here I am Equating 2 Objects
        }
```

Comment: what is `key`, `map` and `tds`? can you provide [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to understand, and created example, and it works. No value in map is replaced.

http://jsfiddle.net/wasikuss/nrun0dty/

Also `var oCount = Object.create(null);` can be replaced to `var oCount = {};`